# Separate training and deploy

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying a code for automated essay grading. With the following code, everytime I run the program it starts training and finally the result is viewed which takes a long time.

I tried out with pickel to separate training and deploy but could not get along.

```
def main():
    print "Fetching data..."
    train_df = util.get_training_data('../data/training_set_rel3.tsv')
    valid_df = util.get_validation_data('../data/valid_set.tsv')

    print "Standardizing scores..."
    train_df, valid_df = util.append_standardized_column(train_df, valid_df, 'score')

print "Calculating perplexity feature..."

train_df, valid_df = Perplexity().fill_perplexity_columns(train_df, valid_df)

print "Calculating number of sentences feature..."

train_df, valid_df = fill_sentence_column(train_df, valid_df)

print "Cleaning for spelling and word count..."
# cleaned up data for spelling feature
vectorizer_train_spelling = util.vectorizer_clean_spelling(train_df)
train_essays_spelling = vectorizer_train_spelling['essay'].values
vectorizer_valid_spelling = util.vectorizer_clean_spelling(valid_df)
valid_essays_spelling = vectorizer_valid_spelling['essay'].values

print "Calculating total words feature..."

train_df, valid_df = fill_total_words_column(train_df, valid_df, train_essays_spelling, valid_essays_spelling)

print "Calculating unique words feature..."

train_df, valid_df = fill_unique_words_column(train_df, valid_df, train_essays_spelling, valid_essays_spelling)

print "Calculating spelling feature..."
# spelling feature
train_df, valid_df = fill_spelling_column(train_df, valid_df, train_essays_spelling, valid_essays_spelling)

print "Calculating pos tags features..."

train_df, valid_df = fill_pos_columns(train_df, valid_df)

print "Cleaning for TFIDF..."
# cleaned up data for tfidf vector feature
vectorizer_train = util.vectorizer_clean(train_df)
train_essays = vectorizer_train['essay'].values
vectorizer_valid = util.vectorizer_clean(valid_df)
valid_essays = vectorizer_valid['essay'].values

print "Calculating TFIDF features with unigram..."
train_df, valid_df = fill_tfidf_column(train_df, valid_df, train_essays, valid_essays, 1)

# print "Calculating TFIDF features with trigram..."
# train_df, valid_df = fill_tfidf_column(train_df, valid_df, train_essays, valid_essays, 3)

print train_df.head()

print valid_df.head()

COLS = ['essay_set', 'spelling_correct', 'std_sentence_count', 'std_unique_words', 'std_total_words',
        'std_unique_words',
        'ADJ', 'ADP', 'ADV', 'CONJ', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'NUM', 'PRT', 'PRON', 'VERB', '.', 'X', 'std_perplexity',
        'std_score']

train_df = train_df[COLS].join(train_df.filter(regex=("tfidf_*")))
valid_df = valid_df[COLS].join(valid_df.filter(regex=("tfidf_*")))

print train_df.shape
print valid_df.shape

max_essay_set = max(train_df['essay_set'])

linreg_scores_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['essay_set', 'p', 'spearman'])

lasso_scores_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['essay_set', 'alpha', 'p', 'spearman'])
ridge_scores_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['essay_set', 'alpha', 'p', 'spearman'])

alphas = [x * 1.0 / 20 for x in range(20, 0, -1)]

for i in range(1, max_essay_set + 1):

    print ""

    train_x = np.asarray((train_df[train_df['essay_set'] == i]).drop(['essay_set', 'std_score'], axis=1))
    train_std_scores = np.asarray((train_df[train_df['essay_set'] == i])['std_score'], dtype="|S6").astype(np.float)

    regr = LinReg(fit_intercept=False, copy_X=False)
    regr.fit(train_x, train_std_scores)

    valid_x = np.asarray((valid_df[valid_df['essay_set'] == i]).drop(['essay_set', 'std_score'], axis=1))
    valid_pred_std_scores = regr.predict(valid_x)

    linreg_spear, p = Spearman(a=(valid_df[valid_df['essay_set'] == i])["std_score"], b=valid_pred_std_scores)
    linreg_scores_df = linreg_scores_df.append({'essay_set': i, 'p': p, 'spearman': linreg_spear},
                                               ignore_index=True)

    print "Linear for Essay Set " + str(i) + ":", linreg_spear

    for a in alphas:
        ridge = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=a)
        ridge.fit(train_x, train_std_scores)
        valid_pred_std_scores_ridge = ridge.predict(valid_x)

        ridge_spear, p = Spearman(a=(valid_df[valid_df['essay_set'] == i])["std_score"],
                                  b=valid_pred_std_scores_ridge)
        ridge_scores_df = ridge_scores_df.append({'essay_set': i, 'alpha': a, 'p': p, 'spearman': ridge_spear},
                                                 ignore_index=True)

        print "Alpha = " + str(a) + " Ridge for Essay Set " + str(i) + ":", ridge_spear

        lasso = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=a)
        lasso.fit(train_x, train_std_scores)
        valid_pred_std_scores_lasso = lasso.predict(valid_x)

        lasso_spear, p = Spearman(a=(valid_df[valid_df['essay_set'] == i])["std_score"],
                                  b=valid_pred_std_scores_lasso)
        lasso_scores_df = lasso_scores_df.append({'essay_set': i, 'alpha': a, 'p': p, 'spearman': lasso_spear},
                                                 ignore_index=True)

        print "Alpha = " + str(a) + "Lasso for Essay Set " + str(i) + ":", lasso_spear

print linreg_scores_df
print ridge_scores_df
print lasso_scores_df

linreg_scores_df.to_pickle('linreg_scores-01.pickle')
ridge_scores_df.to_pickle('ridge_scores-01.pickle')
lasso_scores_df.to_pickle('lasso_scores-01.pickle')
```

So, I want to separate the training and deploy such that when the user runs the program the output is viewed directly and the training is done only for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sklearn library it has methods to save trained model like.It uses joblib.dump() to save the model and joblib.load() to load the trained model.
Here is the link https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html